# std::string::find not working as expected in c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to verify if a specific string is in the input string and if so do something, based on the found string; but it seems that it is always doing the first task no matter what...

```
if (inputString.find(str1) >= 0)
{
   //do something
}
else if (inputString.find(str2) >= 0)
{
    // do something else
}
else 
{
    std::cout << "Strange" << std::endl;
}
```

It is always entering the `// do something` block no matter if the `str1` is present in `inputString` or not.

If I do

```
int str1pos = inputString.find(str1);
int str2pos = inputString.find(str2);
if (str1pos >= 0)
{
   //do something
}
else if (str2pos >= 0)
{
    // do something else
}
else 
{
    std::cout << "Strange" << std::endl;
}
```

it seems to work. Why is that? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well unsigned integers are always greater than or equal to zero. Did you read the documentation for `string::find`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`inputString.find(str1) >= 0` is always true.

This is because the return type of [`find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) is [`size_t`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstddef/size_t/) which is an *unsigned* integer type, so it cannot be negative. Any decent compiler will give a warning for this comparison.

In your second example, when you convert the return value of `find` to `int`, if `find` returned [`npos`](http://www.cplusplus.com/string::npos), then the value becomes `-1`. That's why `>= 0` works there. But if `find` returned a value greater than `INT_MAX` but not `npos`, the cast would turn the index to a negative value, and your logic would fail.

Therefore, you should compare to `npos` instead:

```
if (inputString.find(str1) != std::string::npos)
```

Answer (score 7):

`std::string::find` returns `std::string::npos` if the input string is not found. To check if the string contains your input string, you must use:

```
if (inputString.find(str1) != std::string::npos)
{
   //do something
}
else if (inputString.find(str2) != std::string::npos)
{
    // do something else
}
else 
{
    std::cout << "Strange" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

When not found, the return value is `std::string::npos`. It could be a positive number. You don't know.

Change your code into

```
if (inputString.find(str1) != std::string::npos)
{
   //do something
}
else if (inputString.find(str2) != std::string::npos)
{
    // do something else
}
else 
{
    std::cout << "Strange" << std::endl;
}
```